# Cropping Span at certain width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

To make my menu responsive, I want to crop one text, when a certain width gets reached. Here is what I have so far:

```
  <span data-ng-if="vm.getContext().contextType === 'ContextA'">
        <span data-ng-bind="vm.getActiveContext().userName | limitTo: 7"></span>
        <span data-ng-if="vm.getActiveContext().userName.length > 7">...</span>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
        <span data-ng-bind="vm.getActiveContext().groupName | limitTo: 7"></span>
         <span data-ng-if="vm.getActiveContext().groupName.length > 7">...</span>
        <span
        data-ng-if="vm.getActiveContext().city">, </span><span
        data-ng-bind="vm.getActiveContext().city"></span>
    </span>
```

The problem is, that the city-value is important and shouldn't be cropped. but the user- and groupname should be cropped at for example 900px. How do I accomplish this?

Or what would be an alternative to do it? I know about text-overflow and so on, but since these are combined spans, I couldn't get it to work quit right.

Comment: display:flex or table would allow this with overflow:hidden  and or flex properties, your code as is doesn't help much to set a demo , we only get dots and have no idea about the styling already applied

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make you app responsive, you can define a service, that will be holding current viewport's dimensions. E.g.:

```
// Service to hold current dimensions
function dimensionsService($window) {
  // Defining object, that holds dimensions
  var dimensions = {
    width: $window.innerWidth,
    height: $window.innerHeight,
  }

  // Returning dimensions object to the consumers
  return {
    dimensions: dimensions,
  }
}
dimensionsService.$inject = ['$window'];
```

Then you need to inject this service in any consumer, that need some to perform some actions or calculations based on vieport size. E.g.:

```
function SampleController(service) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.dimensions = service.dimensions;
  vm.cropFilterLength = vm.dimensions.width < 900 ? 5 : 9;

}
SampleController.$inject = ['dimensionsService']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this purpose:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
}
```

which means that for screens with more than 900px the CSS properties that will be applied are the properties that you have on your CSS by default but for screens that has less than 900px the properties of CSS that will be applied are the properties that you have inside this scope.

So, for example if you set one `ID` for `user` span and one for `groupname` span you can do it like follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #user{
       display: none; //Or whatever you want.
    }
    #groupname{
       display: none; //Or whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I also thought about. But this would hide the complete string, I only want to crop it.

Comment: @user5417542 Yes, this will hide it completely. What do you mean with crop? Can you show an image about the expected behaviour? Maybe you can put `width: whatever` to make the spans smaller or `font-size: whatever` to make the text smaller. You can choose among a lot of options but I cannot guess what you are looking for. It is why I put `display: none` by the moment.